# Recombination time for ionized atoms in a low pressure gas?

Tags: electrons, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, inert-gases

I am looking into some new physics and had the following question come up:

You have a neutral gas of let's say, CO atoms at 1 nanoTorr. An electron(s) comes passing through the gas ionizing only 1% of the gas atoms. How long does it take for the gas to come back to neutrality? In other words, what is the recombination time? Any help or guidance of texts to read would be very helpful!![image]